# Notification show as input textbox click with jquery patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> I don't know that I will explain my question well or not because I'm new on stack overflow. I've read the T&C and have tried my best to explain what I want to accomplish. I hope you understand what I'm asking.

I would like to create a system using javascript or jQuery that will display a popup box on the top or bottom of a browser window with custom text and colors defined in my css styles. The "notification" would tell users to about what they need to do in the text box like "Write your email" etc.

This is the code that will show you what I'd like them to look like:

```html
<div class="warning"id="notification"><span>This is default message show first time</span></div>

<div class="information" id="notification"><span>Enter your registered Email ID</span></div>

 <div class="error" id="notification"><span>Email ID is incorrect</span></div>

<div class="error" id="notification"><span>Email is correct - good : show me for 5 sec only after I will hide automatically if I am in green else show until cursor inside textbox.</span></div>

<input type="text" name="email" id="username"/>
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="phone"/>
<input type="submit" id="ok" name="done"/>

<style>#notification {
 position:fixed;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center; 
 z-index:99;
 overflow:hidden; 
}
#notification h2{
 font-size:16px; 
 font-weight:400
}
/*#notification.showNote{
 width:50%; 
 left:230px
}*/
    /*error, info, notice, alert*/
.success,.warning,.error,.information{display: block; position: relative; padding:5px 20px}
.information{background-color:#3bafda}
.success{background-color:#8cc152}
.warning{background-color:#f6bb42}
.error{background-color:#e9573f}
.notify h2{color:#fff}</style>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript or jquery code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

1. `id`s are unique in each page. You can not define multiple elements with just one `id`. Instead, You should use `class` attribute`.
2. To do something after some seconds, You should use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function
3. You must know about jQuery selectors and some of its functions. Read available [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) on the web.
4. To validate a value, You must know [Regex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

A simple working example of your question is this. Hope it helps

```js
let time2Hide = 5000;

function f(selector) {
  $(selector).show();
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(selector).hide();
  }, time2Hide);
}

f("#warning");

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

function onSubmit() {
  let email = $("#email").text()
  if(!email) {
    f("#information"  )
  }
  else if(validateEmail(email)) {
    f("#success");
  }
  else {
    f("#error")
  }
}
```

```css
/**********************************************/

/* notification styles */

.notification {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.notification h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400
}


/*#notification.showNote{
 width:50%; 
 left:230px
}*/


/*error, info, notice, alert*/

#success,
#warning,
#error,
#information {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 20px
}

#information {
  background-color: #3bafda
}

#success {
  background-color: #8cc152
}

#warning {
  background-color: #f6bb42
}

#error {
  background-color: #e9573f
}

.notify h2 {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="warning" class="notification">
  <span>This is default message show first time</span>
</div>

<div id="information" class="notification">
  <span>Enter your registered Email ID</span>
</div>

<div id="error" class="notification">
  <span>Email ID is incorrect</span>
</div>

<div id="success" class="notification">
  <span>Email is correct - good : show me for 5 sec only after I will hide automatically if I am in green else show until cursor inside textbox.</span>
</div>

<hr><br><br><br>

<input type="email" name="email" id="username" />
<input type="phone" name="mobile" id="phone" />
<input type="submit" id="ok" name="done" onclick="onSubmit()"/>
```

---

```js
let time2Hide = 5000;

function hideAll() {
  $("#error").hide();
  $("#warning").hide();
  $("#success").hide();
  $("#information").hide();
}

function show(selector) {
  hideAll();
  $(selector).show();
}

function showNHide(selector) {
  hideAll();
  $(selector).show();
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(selector).hide(); show("#warning");
  }, time2Hide);
}

$("#username")
  .on("input click", () => {
  show("#information");
})
  .on("input", () => {
  let email = $("#username").val();
  if (!email) {
    show("#information");
  } else if (validateEmail(email)) {
    showNHide("#success");
  } else {
    show("#error");
  }
})
.on('focusout', () => {
  show("#warning");
});

function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

function onSubmit() {
  let email = $("#username").val();
  if (!email) {
    show("#information");
  } else if (validateEmail(email)) {
    showNHide("#success");
  } else {
    show("#error");
  }
}

show("#warning");
```

```css
/**********************************************/


/* notification styles */

.notification {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.notification h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400
}


/*#notification.showNote{
 width:50%; 
 left:230px
}*/


/*error, info, notice, alert*/

#success,
#warning,
#error,
#information {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 20px
}

#information {
  background-color: #3bafda
}

#success {
  background-color: #8cc152
}

#warning {
  background-color: #f6bb42
}

#error {
  background-color: #e9573f
}

.notify h2 {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="warning" class="notification">
  <span>This is default message show first time</span>
</div>

<div id="information" class="notification">
  <span>Enter your registered Email ID</span>
</div>

<div id="error" class="notification">
  <span>Email ID is incorrect</span>
</div>

<div id="success" class="notification">
  <span>Email is correct - good : show me for 5 sec only after I will hide automatically if I am in green else show until cursor inside textbox.</span>
</div>

<hr><br><br><br>

<input type="email" name="email" id="username" />
<input type="phone" name="mobile" id="phone" />
<input type="submit" id="ok" name="done" onclick="onSubmit()" />
```

Comment: Did you check the update? If you enter correct email and focus out(click somewhere out of that input) then it validate the email and show the message! When the default message is going to be shown? @Sharadjoshp

Comment: Check now @Sharadjoshp

Comment: Just code like email. what's the problem? try to write that part yourself and put that code in question. @Sharadjoshp

Comment: which yellow image? check again @Sharadjoshp

Comment: That's another question and I saw that you asked! You can accept this answer if it is true and If I know that. I will help you on other question.@Sharadjoshp